# vlookup extract info from different excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a user-form with `Vlookup`. The information is stored in a different workbook. How can I extract the information I need from different excel workbook into my text fields using the following VBA code?

```
Private Sub Textan_AfterUpdate()

'check to see if value exists        
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(C:\Users\poury\Desktop\ADDON Order Tool\AL010.xlsx.Sheet2.Range("B:B"), Me.Textan.Value) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "This is an incorrect Article Number"
    Me.Textan.Value = ""    
    Exit Sub
End If

With Me    
    Textan1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 2, 0)
    Textan2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 3, 0)
    Textan3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 4, 0)
    Textan4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 5, 0)
    Textan5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 6, 0)
    Textan6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 7, 0)
    Textan7 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 8, 0)
    Textan8 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 9, 0)    
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the workbook behind the scenes:

```
Private Sub Textan_AfterUpdate()

Application.Screenupdating = false

Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\poury\Desktop\ADDON Order Tool\AL010.xlsx")

Dim Sheet2 as Worksheet
Set Sheet2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'change name as needed

'check to see if value exists        
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("B:B"), Me.Textan.Value) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "This is an incorrect Article Number"
    Me.Textan.Value = ""    
    Exit Sub
End If

With Me    
    Textan1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 2, 0)
    Textan2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 3, 0)
    Textan3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 4, 0)
    Textan4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 5, 0)
    Textan5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 6, 0)
    Textan6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 7, 0)
    Textan7 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 8, 0)
    Textan8 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Textan), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 9, 0)    
End With

wb.Close false

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor your code and take advantage of sort of a relationship between your textbox names and "Lookup" range columns to retrieve

```
Private Sub Textan_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rowIndex as Variant

    Application.Screenupdating = False

    With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\poury\Desktop\ADDON Order Tool\AL010.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Lookup") '<--| open needed workbook and reference its "Sheet2" "Lookup" range (change "Sheet2" to your actual sheet name)
        rowIndex = Application.Match(Me.Textan.Value, .Columns(1), 0) '<--| try searching "Lookup" range first column for 'Textan' value 
        If IsError(rowIndex) Then 'check to see if value exists   
            MsgBox "This is an incorrect Article Number"
            Me.Textan.Value = ""                  
        Else
            For iText = 1 to 8
                Me.Controls("Textan" & iText) = .Cells(rowIndex, iText+ 1)
            Next
        End If
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False '<--| close opened workbook
    Application.Screenupdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. it did solve my problem

Comment: @PouryaAshena https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rowIndex As Variant
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("F:\My DAFM Project_v1\Employee Data Base File_2019.xlsx").Worksheets("EmpData").Range("A:E")
rowIndex = Application.Match(Me.TextBox9.Value.Cells(y, 11), 0)

Dim EmpData As Worksheet
Set EmpData = wb.Worksheets("EmpData") 'changed file name as needed

If IsError(rowIndex) Then
Me.TextBox9.Value = ""

'check to see if value exists
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(EmpData.Range("A:e"), Me.TextBox9.Value) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "This is an Incorrect SAP ID"
    Me.TextBox9.Value = ""

    Exit Sub
End If

With Me
    TextBox10.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.TextBox9), EmpData.Range("b:E"), 3, 0)
    TextBox11.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.TextBox9), EmpData.Range("b:E"), 4, 0)
    TextBox12.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.TextBox9), EmpData.Range("b:E"), 5, 0)

End With

wb.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: If you add four spaces before each line of code, it'll be highlighted accordingly and will be easier to read. It would also be helpful if you add some commentary on why your answer is helpful, so that people know which are the key lines in your response.